# Android runtime exception. Unable to start activity

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am working on a very simple wallpaper setter. The app works fine on emulator, but does not work on device. I've tried the app on other devices too, and the result is same.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    ImageView iv;
    FloatingActionButton fab,fab2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.plus_24x24);
        fab.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select     Picture"), 9999);

            }
        });
        fab2=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab2);
        fab2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        fab2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_white);
        fab2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        fab2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
                    = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(((BitmapDrawable)iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap());
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Wallpaper set", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 9999 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            fab2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            iv.setImageURI(imageUri);

       }
        else {
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "No image selected", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android.support.design="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ef_margin_medium"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/ef_margin_medium"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/ef_margin_medium"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/ef_margin_medium"
    ads:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    ads:cardElevation="6dp"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/ef_margin_medium"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/ef_margin_medium"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/ef_margin_medium"
        />

    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="51dp"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/card_view" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Error log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.entripleaardee.incognitogallery, PID: 4571
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.entripleaardee.incognitogallery/com.entripleaardee.incognitogallery.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #55: Binary XML file line #55: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

Comment: Please provide next few  strings from your log message.

Comment: Probably show your manifest file to. Does it have `<activity android:name=".MainActivity" >`?

Comment: You have an error in line #55 which is on <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>. Seems you don't have the support library. I believe FAB is in the com.android.support:design. You can just add "compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'" into your gradle dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have to additional namespaces in one file:

```
xmlns:ads
```

and

```
xmlns:app
```

Remove `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` from `RelativeLayout` tag and replace each occurence of `ads` with `app`.

Comment: This is the site, where you can get answers to your programmic questions. However to know if the answer is valuable to others it has to be marked as solved and maybe given points. You can contribute to this site's evolution by ticking a mark sign next to my answer and giving it upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your `xmlns:ads` to `xmlns:app`. Like -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android.support.design="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
```